# Add bash script on linux to create users

Tags: php, linux, bash, passwords

I ask for your help to create a script to create a user and a password on 1 click

```
useradd client1 -M -s /bin/false
passwd client1
```

To have for instance a new user with:

> login: client1 password: test

Is it possible ? and if it is, how please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find it :

First Script create user: (add_user.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh
useradd $1 -M -s /bin/false
```

Second one create a password or change it:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1:$2" | chpasswd
```

Do you know how i can call this script from php file ?

```
<?php
    Execution (add_user.sh) ? 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
adduser client1 -p $(perl -e'print crypt("test", "aa")')
```

Comment: No, the -p parameter expects the password encrypted, says the documentation. Read reference from my answer above.

Comment: Hehe. I don't know a thing about Perl but what you did there is cool. I didn't know it was possible but I wonder what crypto algorithm will it use? Will work for sure?

Comment: It just generates a crypt of password "test" with salt "aa". The salt can be any two characters and will be carried over to the first two characters of the password too.

Answer (score 1):

man useradd will give you hints to do this and I believe this is how:

useradd [username] -d /path_to_home_directory -p [encrypted_password]

now, VERY IMPORTANT, the documentation for useradd says that the -p parameter expects the password ENCRYPTED as returned by crypt(7); therefore, what you need to do is create a sample user with password "test" for example, then open up /etc/shadow and copy and paste the password from the file and use it on your script.

Suppose that "test" encrypted in /etc/shadow appears as "zxs1@431sa" your final script should be:

useradd [username] -d /path_to_home_dir -p zxs1@431sa [enter]

That should do it, I think.

References: http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd